# Modify Dynamically Created (jQuery) Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I have this `<li>`, that when you click it, it creates another `<li>` before it (with a bunch of classes applied to it), which is all working great.. Problem is, I can't modify (via jQuery) the newly created `<li>` elements because they were created dynamically.

Currently, it is setup as:

```
 $(".foo").on("click", function() {
//Blah blah blah
});
```

And I have already tried the code below instead, which still did not work.

```
$(".foo").on("click", function() {
//Blah blah blah
});
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: How do you generate the `<li>`?

Comment: @Michael 

$(".foo").click(function() {
    $(this).before(t);
});

Comment: How exactly are you trying to modify the elements?

Comment: @FelixKling Via another really simple function, that just adds a class using .toggleClass()

Comment: Could you please show how you are trying to retrieve the new elements and apply that method? Since it is possible to call (nearly) any method on newly created elements, something must be wrong in your code. If you don't post your code, all we can do is guess, which is a waste of our and your time. Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo as well.

Comment: @FelixKling Updated the original post with the full code.

Comment: And what does your HTML look like? Any chance of providing a JS Fiddle demo to *show* us what's going on?

Comment: @DavidThomas I would rather not show the HTML, as this is a pretty big project, and I don't just wanna throw up the code for anyone. Also, in this situation, I do not see how it would help.

Comment: Well, it *might* help us understand why several answers "aren't working," which I assumed would be useful to you. It doesn't have to be your *real* HTML, just enough to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @DavidThomas Alright, I stripped down the HTML/CSS as much as possible, but it still has the same general structure. Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eyfHM/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
  $("ul").on('mouseup', '.item', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("completed");
  });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eyfHM/3/).

The problem you were having is that the `.item` elements weren't present in the DOM at the point at which the `mouseup` event was bound to them. This approach binds the `mouseup` to the `ul` which *does* exist, and uses the `on()` method to listen for that event and, if the target element matches the selector (`.item`) passed to the method it implements the anonymous function (the third argument passed to the method).

If the target does *not* match that selector then the event either does nothing or contiunues to propagate through the ancestors.

Comment: Aha! Awesome, ok we're getting somewhere. This helps a lot, thank you. It's working t the extent that it now adds the class. But unfortunately, the created `<li>` is still not working with the second class that is applied to it when created: 'editable', which goes along with http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

Comment: Then you need to edit your question to add the relevant details *here*. What should happen with the 'editable' class?

Comment: Ok, sorry about that, I'm a StackOverflow noob.. Anyways, it works with 'Jeditable', which allows to edit the text in-place va the jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Since li are created dynamically for jQuery v1.7 tto attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.

```
$(document).on("click", ".foo", function() {
    //Blah blah blah
});
```

Essentially if you are using 1.7 and above you're syntax is slightly incorrect for [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but unfortunately, I am still not able to modify the element after it's created. Thanks anyways though!

Answer (score 0):

**JQuery 1.7+**

I think it should  work with the [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function:

```
$(".foo").on('click', function() {
    // more code
});
```

**Other**

```
$(".foo").live('click', function(){
    // more code
}
```

Comment: Please read the full question. And your code examples are not equivalent. This is not how you do event delegation with `.on`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I tried... It creates the <li> successfully, but it still does not allow me to modify it after it is created.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the event to an already present parent element:

```
$('#parent').on('click', '.foo', function() {
    ...
});
```

`'#parent'` would probably be a selector for your `<ul>` element.

Comment: Thanks, but again, that creates the <li> successfully, but I am still not able to modify it (via jQuery) after.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?:

```
$(function() {

  var task =
    $('<li class="editable todo-item">Double Click to Edit</li>');

  $(document).on('click', '.todo-new', function() {
    $('.todo-new').before(task);
  });

  $(document).on('dblclick', '.todo-item', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("todo-completed");
  });

});
```

Comment: (You might want to use the "dblclick" event.)

Comment: Modifiying the code in the question in a fundamental way while people are reading and replying is not a good idea. Anyways, in an earlier version of the code you had posted http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14671652/revisions you had "Double Click to Edit".

Comment: Ok I am sorry, I'll keep that in mind for next time. But even still, your answer unfortunately did not help, as that is not even where the dblclick is used in my code.

Comment: If you paste the exact code it should work. At least it works here. Regarding the double-click: The above code generates an element with your text "Double Click to Edit", and when you double-click it, the class gets toggled.

Comment: Yeah that's what I mean, I don't have it to setup to toggle the class when double clicked. The double click has to to with the 'editable' class that relates to the jQuery plugin 'Jeditable'